# Deleting a Talend service starts the service

Tags: talend

I have deployed a service in ESB Conductor. Next, I stop it and undeploy it.

In Service Locator it is not visible anymore.

Now I delete it, in ESB Conductor. I look in Service Locator and, lo and behold, the service is running! I cannot delete it, because the Delete button is disabled.

How is this possible?

How do I delete the service?

I tried to add, deploy and undeploy again, but that does not help. I am using Talend 6.5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An experience Talend user told me off-line that by using the Apache Karaf Web Console you can see much more than in the Talend management windows. And there I saw active bundles, which were not shown in the Talend management windows. It is possible to delete these bundles in the Apache Karaf Web Console. This solved my problem.

The same person told me that this corruption of services/bundles happens sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

Issues like this are common while using (TAC) -> Talend Administration Console.
The most likely cause of this behaviour is that the bundle of service is still active.

To Resolve the issue , try the following.
**From TAC** -> You could run "unDeploy" , multiple times 2 -3 times to see if the service is down.

If it doesnt Help : Solution -> **Uninstall** the service from **Karaf Command line Console.**

- Logon to the server where the service is deployed.
- Navigate to Talend runtime/bin folder start the Karaf client console.

To Retrieve the bundleId of Service which is Active.

```
bundle:list | grep <serviceName>
```

To Uninstall the service,

```
bundle:uninstall <id>
```

Reference : https://karaf.apache.org/manual/latest/quick-start.html#_stopping_and_uninstalling_the_sample_application

**Incase the bundleId failed to appear with the list command**

You could try the

```
feature:uninstall <servicename>-feature
```

Reference : https://karaf.apache.org/manual/latest-2.x/commands/features-uninstall.html